# About .gitignore: trying to unignore new directories

Tags: git

I have this `~/.gitignore` file:

```
*
!ranktracker_projects/*
ranktracker_projects/*.bak
!*/
!.vim/
!.vim/*/
!.vim/bundle
!.vim/plugin/*
!.vim/bundle/*
!.vim/ftplugin/*
!.vim/doc/*
!.xchat2/servlist_.conf
!.fonts/*
```

The problem, when I create for example a directory inside `~/.vim/bundle` I dont get the new directory in the untracked files list.

Comment: `!.vim/bundle/*` the `*` indicates you ignore everything in that directory, including subdirectories

Comment: @TimCastelijns but I thought that `!` before unignores

Comment: Can't you force to add files with `git add`, ignoring `.gitignore` if you specify the path?

Comment: @omeinusch sorry but I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `!` in this way, see the [manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded

You should be more specific with your ignores.